# Convert table to partition and columnstore index on different key

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, columnstore

I have a table with the following characteristics:

- 200 million rows
- A clustered primary key that is an auto-incrementing BIGINT column
- An NVARCHAR(MAX) column consisting of raw JSON data, which we never use JSON functions against.
- A DATETIME column
- No partitions

I want to do the following:

- Create partitions on the DATETIME column so I can partition by month
- Create a clustered columnstore index on the table/partition scheme scheme and order by DATETIME column.

The columnstore index will help compress the data and speed up queries, and the partition will help me with data retention with columnstore - drop partitions by month instead of the costly deletes.

The steps I've tested out on a smaller replica db:

1. Create the partition function and scheme on DATETIME column
2. Drop all nonclustered indexes
3. Drop the PK constraint on the BIGINT column
4. Create clustered columnstore index on DATETIME column and DATETIME partition

Steps 3 and 4 are pretty quick on the smaller test db, but on a copy of our production db it takes forever, and this is on Azure database (2022) with hyperscale.

I understand why steps 3 and 4 take a long time. I'm asking if there is something different that i can do to optimize or simplify the process.

My next step would be to provision an empty table that is configured with the partition and columnstore index, and re-insert all 200 million rows, then drop old table, rename new table. But I will try that if there is no other option with what I have above.

UPDATE:

I tried using the import/export wizard to copy the data from original table to the provisioned table but it took 16 minutes to copy 1 mil rows, and at this rate it would take 53 hours to move 200 mil rows.

Comment: Note a CCI is not "on a column".  It includes all the columns, and has no special access by any key column.  Instead of changing the key, you could just partition by your "auto-incrementing BIGINT", and use ranges of that to drop older partitions.

Comment: Switching or truncating partitions is always a metadata operation.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - thank you, I mis-communicated my intention about columnstore - I meant that I would create a columnstore index on the table, but order by DATETIME.  I will update my comment above.

Comment: @J.D. - my mistake, I misunderstood how deletes worked with columnstore